# Personalized Suggestions in the app Google Keyboard

Tags: android, dictionary, keyboard

Google has updated the keyboard app to version 3.0. 
It is introduced the feature "Personalized Suggestions". The keyboard app can read and process the texts from other Google applications. 
It is said, that the data from this function are only stored locally. Is that really so?

My question is: in which directory, in which file the suggestions data are stored?
Are they included in the userdict(ionary)-files, included in the system-app LatinIME.apk, or collected in a new own (sqlite) database file?

If they are included in the user-dictionary, then Google will import that file to his server, if Google`s backup-and-restore-service is enabled. And in the settings of the Google Account  under the heading "Input Tools" there is pointed to the synchronization of user dictionaries: " Your user dictionary stores words that you've recently entered using our tools, and helps improve our accuracy for future conversions. When you enabling syncing, you'll sync your dictionary across Google products (such as Android, Gmail, and Drive). Currently, the user dictionary can only be used with Chinese Pinyin IME."
So in the future for other languages?

Does anyone know exactly?

DLanger